# How to automatically transfer files from pico to connected device

Tags: data-transfer

I'm working on making a cartridge for the adafruit pygamer. My plan was to connect the rpi pico to the pygamer's micro-usd port and have it automatically transfer a uf2 stored on the rpi pico to the pygamer. Unfortunately, I can't find anything that might work for this. Does anyone have an example of how I would do this in micropython or circuitpython?